# Sum expression with a where clause or if

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, report, reporting

How can I write an expression that will only sum values in a list where a column is not null?

example:

2.1    4    5   23

4      1    2   null

1      3.1  5    1

8      .5   1    null

i would like to get the sum of the first column to all rows who doesn't have the last column null. So my answer would be 2.1+1 = 3.1. Is it possible to have a 'where' clause in a Sum expression? Or how could i use the Sum-if to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look whether this helps

```
   select sum(field_1) from table_name where last_field is not null
```

Comment: I was looking for an expression i could possibly add to my report something like =Sum(IIf(cases = 0, hours, 0)) if cases column was 0 then sum up the rows with 0 column in them. But i could try what you suggested in the stored procedure itself.